# Probability limit formula for coefficient in errors in variables regression

Tags: regression, errors-in-variables

I found an online resource which lists the plim formula for a simple regression under the classic errors-in-variables assumption as:
$$
\text{plim }\beta_1=\frac{{\rm Cov}(y, x_1)}{{\rm Var}(x_1)}
$$

- Why is this the case?
- Where does this formula come from?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the "online resource" in question? Note that the formula you list is just the OLS estimator for a regular (non-errors in variables) simple regression model.

Comment: Two very similarly phrased questions in a very short period of time; the other is [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/84205/probability-limit-calculation). Is this the same person twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not sure I understand the question, but for a simple regression model

$$
Y = \alpha + \beta X + \epsilon,
$$
where $X$ and $\epsilon$ are independent, we have

$$\frac{\mathop{\text{Cov}}(Y, X)}{\mathop{\text{Var}} X}=\frac{\mathop{\text{Cov}}(\alpha+\beta X + \epsilon, X)}{{\mathop{\text{Var}} X}}=\frac{\beta\mathop{\text{Cov}}(X, X)}{\mathop{\text{Var}} X}=\beta\frac{\mathop{\text{Var}} X}{\mathop{\text{Var}} X}=\beta.$$

Similar formulas hold for the sample estimates of these quantities. Taking limits on the sample estimates will then give you the requested convergence in probability.