# Probability limit calculation

Tags: self-study, errors-in-variables

My class notes list the following steps for calculating a plim under classic errors in variables:
$$
{\rm plim}\ \beta_1 = \frac{{\rm cov}(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \epsilon - \beta_1 e, x_1)}{{\rm var}(x_1)}=\frac{\beta_1 {\rm var}(x_1) - \beta_1 {\rm cov}(x_1, e)}{{\rm var}(x_1)}...
$$
How was the simplification in the numerator done?

Comment: Please provide a link to the resource in question. Also, please register your account.

Comment: I do not have the link, this formula was recorded in class notes.

Comment: We welcome questions like this, @user995, but we treat them differently. Please tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you are stuck, & we'll try to provide hints to get you unstuck. To better understand the process, you should read the [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) for the `[self-study]` tag.

Comment: I understand the definition of plim and the construction of the first fraction, but not how the notes go from the first fraction to the second one.

Comment: Two very similarly phrased questions in a very short period of time; the other is [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/84191/probability-limit-formula-for-coefficient-in-errors-in-variables-regression). Is this the same person twice?

Comment: The previous question did not go beyond the first equation of the formula and only asked about the general setup. This is another question which has to do with the specific simplification.

Comment: Expand the brackets, and write down each term, you'll see the answer instantly

Answer (score -1):

When you open the brackets in the numerator the first term is cov(Beta0) or var (beta0) =0 as variance of a constant is 0. The second term will be beta1 times var(X1). This time we don't take variance of beta1 and make it zero as it is multiplied with a random variable x. So we just take variance of x and multiply it by beta1. Then we move to the third term which is variance of epsilon which I guess is again assumed to be a constant. The final term is beta1 e and x1. I guess e here is your error term therefore the final term will be cov( e, x1).

Comment: How did the third term become "the variance of epsilon"?